# How do you eliminate a second join on the same table if the condition is similiar?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a PostgreSQL database with a table consisting of UserIDs (`id_u`) and parent UserIDs (`id_p`). All users have some attributes stored in other tables which are accessible through a view (`v_attr`). The view aggregates the attributes and outputs them into a string, which I want to output alongside the ID for both the user and its parent. The query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT users.id_u, u.attribs, users.id_p, p.attribs FROM users
LEFT JOIN v_attr AS u ON u.id_u = users.id_u
LEFT JOIN v_attr AS p ON p.id_u = users.id_p
```

The output is good but because the view aggregates a lot of data, querying it twice takes a lot of time. Can I somehow optimize this query such that the second join is not required?

I am using PostgreSQL version 13, however I cannot use CTE. Limitation in a driving application.

Comment: Since you need two different pieces of info, what alternative could there be other than to fetch/compute each of them?  You could fetch them "vertically" rather than "horizontally" by using a union rather than a join, but would that really change the amount of work to be done?  Maybe you can turn the view into a materialized view with the appropriate index.  Or with an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of the query, maybe there is a way to optimize it that doesn't depend on eliminating the join.